# Chrome Inspect Device not showing android app

Tags: android, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, usb-debugging

I am trying to debug this app using *chrome://inspect* - Devices, but I am not able to see my app in the debug app list. I can see the device name and only Chrome app under it, but not my app.

Settings that I have applied

- Enable USB Debugging (Android Device)
- Discover USD Devices (Chrome Dev Tools)
- Select Debug app - App Name
- Use USB for - File Transfer
- Added **android:debuggable="true"** in Manifest file

I have also tried using different USB cables, different android device, but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found answer on [Remote Debugging WebViews](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/webviews?hl=en#configure-webviews-for-debugging) on Google Developers.

This method has been added in [API Level 19](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(boolean)), hence had to add following check

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
  WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```

As mentioned in documentation, this method does not respect *debuggable* flag in application manifest file. If you want to enable webview debugging only when *debuggable* flag is true, then add one more check

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
  if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE))
  { 
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true); 
  }
}
```