# Chrome remote devices not showing Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

I'm trying to get a Cordova (= webview) app showing in the Chrome inspector *remote devices*, but it's not working.

It seems everything is OK with the developer options, since:

- The phone is detected by the Chrome tool, but the tool says "No browsers detected" when my app is running on the phone ;
- If I launch a browser on my phone, then the tool allows me to inspect it.

My coworker has the exact same phone (OnePlus One) and it works for him (he can inspect when the app is running). The difference is his phone is rooted.

We tried *my phone on his PC* and *his phone on my PC*: it didn't work with my phone but it worked with his.

We tried another phone, it didn't work on any PC.

I checked this: [Chrome inspect devices not showing device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156594/chrome-inspect-devices-not-showing-device) but it doesn't change anything.

I checked this: [Chrome Inspect Device not showing android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39264489/chrome-inspect-device-not-showing-android-app) but since it's a webapp with Cordova, I'm not sure I'm suppose to do something like that, plus it works for my cowoker with the same app so it would be strange if *I* need to do this but not him.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome device inspect cannot find Ionic Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028990/chrome-device-inspect-cannot-find-ionic-application)

Comment: Take a look of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028990/chrome-device-inspect-cannot-find-ionic-application/41029430#41029430), I believe that the problem could be the Android Version (That should be >= 4.4)

Comment: I'll check this but is it the version of Android on the phone or the app SDK? My Android version is 6.x and the app SDK is 4.2.2 (which could be the problem but still it works on my coworker phone). Plus I add in the question that my coworker's phone is rooted.

Answer (score 15):

In order for Chrome to detect in app 'WebView' of your Cordova application, your Cordova application must be of 'debug' version obtained from Cordova build. If your Cordova application is of 'release' version, Chrome will not be able to detect the 'WebView'

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 User Just Install the new version of Microsoft Edge and Open [edge://inspect/#devices](http://edge://inspect/#devices).

Answer (score -1):

I have a contribution :)

Download [ADB](http://adbshell.com/upload/adb.zip), put on `C:\` drive under `adb` folder (C:\adb),

open Command Prompt (cmd), do:

`cd C:\adb && adb devices`

It will enable daemon, and device will be showed in Chrome inspector.

---

*An alternative to download adb is to use adb from Android Studio program folder.*

Be happy.

Comment: Sorry, I clicked down vote by mistake. When possible, edit your answer with any minor changes and then I will remove my down vote xD